AWS CDK lambda versioning keep latest 2 versions for smooth update deployments
I am using AWS CDK to deploy my stacks, they contain Lambda functions and Step functions.
The step functions use the lambdas in their execution flow, I wanted to make sure that if a new deployment is pushed with cdk deploy, the step functions that are already running will use the previous version of the lambdas, that was deployed previously with the step function.
Some of my lambdas also require provisioned concurrency, which I must use Alias or Version for
for that, I try to use lambda versionining the following way:
import * as python from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-python-alpha";
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { DockerImage, Duration } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { PolicyStatement } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import { execSync } from "child_process";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { artifactoryIndexUrl } from "../../../utils/jfrog";
import { FunctionVersionProps } from "../common/function-version";

export interface PythonFunctionProps extends python.PythonFunctionProps {}

export class PythonFunction extends python.PythonFunction {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PythonFunctionProps) {
    const stack = cdk.Stack.of(scope);

    const pipCacheDir = execSync("pip cache dir").toString().trim();
    const poetryCacheDir = execSync("poetry config cache-dir").toString().trim();

    super(scope, id, {
      timeout: Duration.seconds(30),
      tracing: lambda.Tracing.ACTIVE,
      bundling: {
        image: DockerImage.fromBuild(__dirname, {
          buildArgs: {
            IMAGE: props.runtime.bundlingImage.image,
          },
        }),
        commandHooks: {
          beforeBundling(inputDir: string, outputDir: string): string[] {
            return [`pip config set global.index-url ${artifactoryIndexUrl}`];
          },
          afterBundling(inputDir: string, outputDir: string): string[] {
            return [];
          },
        },
        assetExcludes: ["**/__pycache__", "**/*.pyc", "**/*.pyo", "**/.pytest_cache", "**/tests", "README.md"],
        assetHashType: cdk.AssetHashType.SOURCE,
        volumes: [
          {
            hostPath: pipCacheDir,
            containerPath: "/tmp/pip-cache",
          },
          {
            hostPath: poetryCacheDir,
            containerPath: "/tmp/poetry-cache",
          },
        ],
      },
      ...props,
    });

    this.addToRolePolicy(
      new PolicyStatement({
        actions: ["ssm:GetParameter"],
        resources: [`arn:${stack.partition}:ssm:${stack.region}:${stack.account}:parameter/vita-*`],
      })
    );
  }

  version(props?: FunctionVersionProps): lambda.IFunction {
    const id = this.node.id;
    const version = this.currentVersion;
    const aliasName = `v${version.version}`;
    return new lambda.Alias(this, `${id}Alias`, {
      aliasName,
      version,
      ...(props?.provisionedConcurrency && { provisionedConcurrentExecutions: props?.provisionedConcurrency.value }),
    });
  }
}

export interface FunctionVersionProps {
  provisionedConcurrency?: {
    value: number;
  };
}

the method .version is then used in my step functions
prepareSegmentsFn: prepareSegmentsFn.version({
        provisionedConcurrency: {
          value: 1,
        },
      }),

The problem is that using .currentVersion gets me the current new version when deployed (this version + 1), but it deletes the previous version
Then I encounter errors in my step function that the function I'm trying to call cannot be called
{
  "Error": "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
  "Cause": "User: arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/Stack-***-***/*** is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:***:function:Stack-SharedDeleteModelFn659FE70B-2IgdOOYDRn78:v34 because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID: ***)"
}

